# How to fix text indenting of two blocks in the same row

Tags: html, css

I have stumbled upon an issue with indenting. If you look at this part of my website:

[image]

I displayed two pictures, and aligned them with "Author", "Titel" and a "Dummy description".

Here is my HTML markup:

```
<img class="book-covers" src="../images/BookCovers/books.jpg" alt="Book">        
            <span>
            </span>
            <p class="text-book">
                <br>
                <br>
                Author<br>
                Titel<br>
                Dummy description
            </p>

            <img class="book-covers" src="../images/BookCovers/HowToReadABOOK.jpg" alt="Book">        
            <span>
            </span>
            <p class="text-book">
                author<br>
                Titel<br>
                Dummy description
            </p>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.text-book
{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px 15px;
  font-size: 90%;
  width: 450px;
}

.book-covers
{
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 12%;
}
```

As you can see in my HTML code, I inserted `<br>
                                          <br>`  under the first `<p class="text-book">` you come across.

My problem is: the text aligned next to the second image of *How to Read a Book* also line breaks along for some reason, which I do not want.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: What does the parent look like? Since they are horizontal, there must be some styling on the parent causing that. I put your code into a fiddle and it looks fine. Look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/TrevinAvery/ed97jcnz/6/) and tell me what's different.

Comment: @TrevinAvery thank you for your answer. I already solved my problem. It was indeed the styling on the parent causing this.

Comment: You should add an answer and mark it correct for posterity.